# Read a directory as bytes

Tags: io, dart

I'm trying to build an archive file using the [Archive package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/archive) and I need to archive a whole directory.

So far I see that I can archive a single file by doing this:

```dart
io.File file = new io.File(pathToMyFile);
List<int> bytes = await file.readAsBytes();
io.FileStat stats = await file.stat();

Archive archive = new Archive();
archive.addFile(new ArchiveFile.noCompress('config.yaml', stats.size, bytes)
  ..mode = stats.mode
  ..lastModTime = stats.modified.millisecond);

List<int> data = new ZipEncoder().encode(archive, level: Deflate.NO_COMPRESSION);

await new io.File('output.war').writeAsBytes(data, flush: true);
```

But the to create an `ArchiveFile` I need the bytes representing the file, however I feel like it would be nice to have the whole directory as Bytes to do this. Is there a way to do this? It seems the Dart API on [Directory](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.Directory) is pretty limited.

How does one usually go to let's say copy a directory? Just call system `cp` ? I mean I would like to get a solution that would work on multiple platforms.

Comment: https://github.com/roberthartung/zip.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it file by file recursively. Grinder has a task for this just take a look at the implementation https://github.com/google/grinder.dart/blob/devoncarew_0.7.0-dev.1/lib/grinder_files.dart#L189

You get all files of a directory with

```dart
var fileList =
      new io.Directory(path.join(io.Directory.current.absolute.path, 'lib'))
          .list(recursive: true, followLinks: false);
```

and then you process one file after the other.

Comment: And just out of curiosity, have you tried creating a directory in an archive? (or would you use the `archive` package at all to create an uncompressed archive file?)

Comment: No I don't know the archive package. It seems not to support such a thing like a directory. Maybe you can just add a file with the relative path `somedir/somesubdir/somefile.xxx` or encode the path in the name.

Comment: Günter is right. Directories are "virtual" and not explicitly added. Just add filenames with their relative path.